# Publish custom object in Open Graph with built-in "publish" action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, custom-action

I have some problems with my first Open Graph custom action:

I've created a custom action ":publish" because with the built-in action "news:publish" I only can publish objects of type "og:article".

This action was rejected with "You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted."

Ok, I understand, but how can I publish custom objects (in my case :recipe) with the built-in action "publish"?
I can not change the connected object types on this bulit-in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish is not a built-in action, it is some sort of reserved word for publishing actions. If you are trying to publish something like article, [built in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/) read action is appropriate for that. If you are publishing custom objects like `recipe`, the appropriate action should be `cook` or similar.

PS: The built in action is not news:publish, it is `news:Read`.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, then I'm trying to find an appropriate name for my custom action.
I'm of course "cook" the recipe, but I "publish" it on my website/blog, so the best name would be of course "publish", but I will surely find another one. ;)

Comment: Yes, you may publish it to your website, but actions really mean the real life actions, like cook, run, upvoted etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make your action name something else that describes it appropriately, but is *not* “publish”.